# Is there any format or convention to making a web site template?

Tags: html, layout, user-interface

Basically, the web site is HTML, but I would like to separate the logic or programming side for programmers (for example, read data from database), and the design for the designer. Is this possible to separate the design as a web site template, for designer to work on, and the programmers just fit the value in? Thanks.

For example, in the iOS development, I give the interface builder for the designer, and the programmer is connect that to their programme to display.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You use a template language. Such as [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/), [Moustache](http://mustache.github.com/), [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Taking things a step further, it is a common to use an MVC framework (such as [Catalyst](http://catalystframework.org/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) or [Cake](http://cakephp.org/)) to divide the logic into Models (business logical and data access), Controllers (dispatch handling and glue) and Views (templates, JSON dumps, etc).